# HTML Signature is different on multiple devices

Tags: html, css, thunderbird

I've tried to Frankenstein together an e-mail signature but I'm failing.

I opened the e-mail on iPhone, Mac Mail, Thunderbird and Gmail and they all look different. Some drop the social icons below the main logo, others drop the gray text.

Fiddle (looking correct): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eCNq.png

Thundermail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJQkj.jpg

Gmail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DqFq.png

Mac mail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZHPl.png

iPhone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZXyh.png

Here's the current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: black;
      }

      td {
        display: table-cell;
      }

      table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        height: 81px;
        width: 250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        display: block;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="width:45px;vertical-align:top"><a href="https://www.corbuk.com" target="_blank"><img style="border:none" width="45" src="https://i.imgur.com/qFFfOdW.png"></a>
        </td>
        <td style="height:45px;vertical-align:top;padding-top:7px;padding-left:15px"><b><span style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;">NAME HERE</span></b><br><span style="color:grey;font-size:10px;font-weight:400;">General Manager</span></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:15px;vertical-align:bottom">
          <a href="#" style="padding-right:5px"><img width="22" src="https://i.imgur.com/L7RBFZu.png" alt="Facebook" style="border:none"></a>
          <a href="#" style="padding-right:5px"><img width="22" src="https://i.imgur.com/Pj2TSoO.png" alt="Instagram" style="border:none"></a>
          <a href="#"><img width="22" src="https://i.imgur.com/qtmS8US.png" alt="Website" style="border:none"></a>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you run Thunderbird with default settings. Like most desktop email clients it blocks external references by default, so you need to include the images inline and not load them from an external site

Answer (score 1):

Some modern mail clients allow non-inline CSS. However, most of the email clients still require you to write your CSS inline, so the table style cannot be at the top of the page but has to be embedded like `<table style="..."></table>`

See https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ for a list which describes which clients allow what tags.

Also, and I don't know if this will make a difference, but use '20px' instead of just '20'.